# looping through obects in objects when prompted

Tags: javascript, loops, object, prompt

How do I loop this through my Object when prompted?

```
var DennisLife = {

        "greetings":{
            hello: " Hi there! ",
            bye: "awe, leaving me already? ok, bye!",
        }       
}

var input = prompt("hello or bye").touppercase();
```

Comment: prompt(DennisLife.greetings.hello) or prompt(DennisLife.greetings.bye)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over the properties of an object using a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, or in more modern browsers you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys into an array then grab one by index or loop over those.

Or if you are trying to get the property that the user typed in:

```
var input = prompt("hello or bye").toLowerCase();
alert(DennisLife.greetings[input]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a direct access with a [property acessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like

```
object.property
object["property"]
object[variable]   // variable = 'property'
```

```js
var DennisLife = {
        greetings: {
            hello: " Hi there! ",
            bye: "awe, leaving me already? ok, bye!",
        }       
    };

var input = prompt("hello or bye").toLowerCase();

alert(DennisLife.greetings[input]);
```